# Retrieve the callback with jQuery.Ajax without the use of success

Tags: jquery, rest, spring-mvc

I Used jQuery.ajax in client side to post some data, i have an error: **unexpected end of input** , but in server side everything works fine,

I followed every instruction to solve this problem, but I can't,

My problem is : I want to use the callbck of the service to validate the data sent to the server, but the error prevents me.

is there a different method to retrieve the callback with Jquery , without the use of this:

```
success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('ok........data' + data);
            },
```

server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deployWorkflow", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String deployWorkflow(@RequestBody ObjectNode jsonData) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(jsonData.toString());
      return "test";
    }
```

client side:

```
 deployWorkflow : function() {
            var rootURL = url;      
            var finalData = this.save(processDefinitionId);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                url : rootURL + "/json/deployWorkflow",
                dataType : "json",
                data : Util.stringify(finalData),
                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('ok........data' + data);
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error:  status:  " + textStatus + " er: " + errorThrown);
                }, 
                done : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log('done....data' + data);
                }

            });
        },
```

Util.stringify

```
stringify : function(value) {
        var _json_stringify = JSON.stringify;
        var _array_tojson = Array.prototype.toJSON;
        delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
        var r=_json_stringify(value);
        Array.prototype.toJSON = _array_tojson;
        return r;
    },
```

Comment: You can use `jQuery.ajax().done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {})`, I don't think that the problem

Comment: You have to fix error prior to go further... Sounds really like an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  You should post the complete request code you are using, maybe just a wrong option (datatype) passed to ajax method

Comment: @A.Wolff :yes you're right, but I tried everything with the error before posting here, but I can not solve it

Comment: @Satpal is not working for me

Comment: @HabibKsentini, Post your actual code let community help you. We will be able to help you only if we see the problematic area. And I am not gona guess this time

Comment: @HabibKsentini I guess this is because you are asking for server to return specific data type but indeed server doesn't return this type of data. Again, you should post this request code you are using and BTW the returned type of data from server

Comment: You are asking for server to return JSON but your server return a string. So return JSON encoded data from server or remove `dataType: "JSON"` from option request